# Flutter app debug problem, Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:5016

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

My app has a debug problem, when I debug the app I saw this error in last 2 or 3 days, please help to solve this: 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps it conflicts with other programs mysql, database program, localhost server?

Comment: Have you solved it? I have same problem as you.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: solved, just add new network config,and show it in androidmanifest